# PHP/Phinx - Inserting Longitude/Latitude causes PDO MySQL geometry object error

Tags: php, mysql, phinx

I'm attempting to create a `CitySeeder` using [Phinx](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx). But I'm getting the following error:

```
[PDOException]                                                                                                         
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Here is my `seeders/CitySeeder.php` class. The `geo_coords` field uses a `POINT` datatype:

```
<?php

use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class CitySeeder extends AbstractSeed
{
    public function run()
    {
        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'birmingham',
                'geo_coords' => 'POINT(0 0)'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'london',
                'geo_coords' => 'POINT(0 0)'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'liverpool',
                'geo_coords' => 'POINT(0 0)'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'manchester',
                'geo_coords' => 'POINT(40 -100)'
            ],
        ];

        $cityTable = $this->table('city');
        $cityTable->insert($data)->save();
    }
}
```

Which is strange because if I enter that manually into the database it works.

Does the longitude/latitude have to be formatted in a certain way? I've tried using an array, and a space separated `long lat` format but I still get the same error. I've even went as far as looking through the source code but can not find anything useful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

I've inspected the code from the Phinx library where the error is happening:

```
public function insert(Table $table, $row)
{
    $this->startCommandTimer();
    $this->writeCommand('insert', array($table->getName()));

    $sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO %s ",
        $this->quoteTableName($table->getName())
    );

    $columns = array_keys($row);
    $sql .= "(". implode(', ', array_map(array($this, 'quoteColumnName'), $columns)) . ")";
    $sql .= " VALUES (" . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($columns), '?')) . ")";

    $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute(array_values($row));
    $this->endCommandTimer();
}
```

The data from `array_values($sql)` at the point of failure is:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(10) "birmingham"
    [1]=>
        string(26) "POINT(0 0)"
}
```

And the query after `$sql` is set:

```
string(55) "INSERT INTO `city` (`name`, `geo_coords`) VALUES (?, ?)"
```

When doing the following after `prepare()`: `die(var_dump($stmt->debugDumpParams()));`:

```
SQL: [55] INSERT INTO `city` (`name`, `geo_coords`) VALUES (?, ?)
Params:  0
NULL
```

Logging the MySQL queries shows the following:

```
2016-12-12T12:53:12.721287Z    12 Query INSERT INTO `city` (`name`, `geo_coords`) VALUES ('birmingham', 'POINT(0, 0)')
```

I believe this is incorrect because the POINT is being inserted as a string?

Comment: Perhaps South Pole is -90 degrees so -100 can't exist :-?

Comment: But it works fine if I write an SQL query to insert `POINT(40 -100)`. Even if I enter `POINT(10, 10)` for example I get the same error.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong anyway. We have a MySQL error but only PHP code to inspect.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm having a hard time getting any MySQL data. Phinx doesn't offer any support to dump the raw SQL query and I can't find anything in MySQL logs.

Comment: I know nothing about that library but appears to be pure PHP code. In the worse case you can simply type a `var_dump()` yourself.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I found the part where it fails in the library and updated the answer. I'm doing a bit of debugging now.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Updated. I logged the queries in MySQL and it seems to be inserting the point as a string? Is that correct?

Comment: Here's where my knowledge ends. I suppose it's all binary data and you can either execute the function that produces it or instruct MySQL to parse and run it from a string but this last case probably requires some syntax I can't tell you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem using the following:

```
<?php

use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class CitySeeder extends AbstractSeed
{
    public function run()
    {
        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'birmingham',
                'geo_coords' => [0, 0],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'london',
                'geo_coords' => [0, 0],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'liverpool',
                'geo_coords' => [0, 0],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'manchester',
                'geo_coords' => [0, 0],
            ],
        ];

        $conn = $this->getAdapter()->getConnection();
        $sth = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO city (`name`, `geo_coords`) VALUES (?, POINT(?, ?))');

        foreach($data as $key => $val)
        {
            $sth->execute([
                $val['name'],
                $val['geo_coords'][0],
                $val['geo_coords'][1]]
            );
        }
    }
}
```